# How do I make Firefox open a PDF in a tab instead of downloading it?

Tags: pdf, firefox

I find it really annoying, that firefox on my Mac (OS X Lion) **automatically downloads a pdf instead of viewing** it in a tab. On Windows this works flawless. But why is it not working on the Mac? **Is there a way to change this?**

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a PDF plugin for Firefox. For instance, [this PDF Browser Plugin](http://www.schubert-it.com/pluginpdf/) will work for that. It will allow you to open a PDF in the browser without downloading it.
More information on [this Firefox support doc.](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Opening%20PDF%20files%20within%20Firefox)